# Powershell : How to get a JSON file content from URI instead of local disk

Tags: json, powershell

Using Get-Content, I had developed my powershell script but later felt to move to cloud using storage repository used for templates.

```
$JsonContent = Get-Content $TFileUri | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Error:

> Get-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.

I attempted adding -Raw parameter which had helped me in other occasions before piping to ConvertFrom-Json but it gave me the following error:

```
$JsonContent = Get-Content $TFileUri -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

> Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw.

How to fetch a file from remote URI and workaround above challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following adaptation helped me move ahead ( not sure how standard the resolution is but sharing to be of some help )

```
$JsonContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $TFileUri
```

Note: I didnt find it necessary to convert JSON to object as well with above line.